# Equation of Circles going through a specific point and touching two lines.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, tangent-line

Question: Find equation of circles touching the lines $3x+4y-35=0$ and $4x+3y+14=0$, and passing through the point $(-1,5)$.

Firstly, I was able to infer that there should be two such circles.
Secondly, I know that the centre of the circles should pass through the acute angle bisector of the two equations, which is $x+y=3$. However, I am unable to proceed nicely, it is getting algebraically complex for me to solve, I'm looking for a fast solution.

One of my Idea was to take $(a,b)$ as the centre of one of the circles.

And solve the following two equations:

$a+b=3$, as $(a,b)$ lies on the angle bisector.

$(a+1)^2 + (b-5)^2= (\frac{3a+4b-35}{5})^2$, equating the radiuses.

However this is getting too long. I'm wondering if there is a simple solution, Like maybe  something involving power of point or some synthetic geometry so that the solving is easier.

Comment: The equations look right; substitute $b=3-a$ and you've just got a quadratic. It can't be *much* simpler, since you know you want two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that the point at which the lines intersect is $I=(-23,26)$. The circle $c$ centered at $I$ with radius $1$ intersects the line $3x+4y=35$ at two points: $\left(-\frac{119}5,\frac{133}5\right)$ and $\left(-\frac{111}5,\frac{127}5\right)$. Among these two, I will pick the point $I_1=\left(-\frac{111}5,\frac{127}5\right)$, which is the one which is closer to $P=(-1,5)$. And now, let $I_2=\left(-\frac{112}5,\frac{126}5\right)$, which is, among the points where $c$ intersects the line $4x+3y=-14$, the one which is closer to $P$. So, the line defined by $I$ and the midpoint $M$ of the line segment joining $I_1$ and $I_2$ bissects the angle $\angle I_1\hat II_2$. But $M$ is the point $\left(-\frac{223}{10},\frac{253}{10}\right)$ and the slope of the line segment joining this point to $I$ is $-1$. Therefore, the line that bissects the angle $\angle I_1\hat II_2$ is the line $\{(-23+t,26-t)\mid t\in\Bbb R\}$.

So, each point of this line is equidistant to the lines $3x+4y=35$ and $4x+3y=-14$. The distance from $(-23+t,26-t)$ to the first line (and hence to the second line) is$$\frac{|3(-23+t)+4(26-t)-35|}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=\frac{|t|}5.$$

Finally, asserting that $P$ belongs to the circle centered at $(-23+t,26-t)$ with radius $\frac{|t|}5$ means that$$(-23+t+1)^2+(26-t-5)^2=\left(\frac{|t|}5\right)^2,$$whose solutions are $t=25$ and $t=\frac{925}{49}$. So, the circles that you are after are the circle centered at $(2,1)$ with radius $5$ and the circle centered at $\left(-\frac{202}{49},\frac{349}{49}\right)$ with radius $\frac{185}{49}$ (see the picture below).

[image]